# 'object' does not contain definition for 'Foo'

Tags: c#

I've looked around quite a lot for the answer to this and can't find it anywhere. I have two assemblies: an 'Engine' assembly and a 'Main' assembly.  In the Engine, I have a singleton manager that contains some Dictionaries. Like this:

```
namespace Engine
{
public class ResourceManager
{
    protected static ResourceManager rscMngr = new ResourceManager();

    private Dictionary<string, WTileMap> maps = new Dictionary<string, WTileMap>();

    public Dictionary<string, WTileMap> Maps
    {
        get { return maps; }
    }

    public static ResourceManager Instance
    {
        get { return rscMngr; }
    }

}
}
```

Then in the 'Main' Assembly, I try to access the singleton like this:

```
Marker startMarker = ResourceManager.Instance.Maps[gameInfo.StartingMap].ObjectLayer.markers[gameInfo.MapMarker];
```

However when I compile, it gives me this error:

> Engine.ResourceManager' does not contain a definition for 'Maps' and
>   no extension method 'Maps' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Engine.ResourceManager' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

However it works if I make the 'maps' variable public and access it through there. Or if the data type is a primitive such as int, float, string etc.

I have no idea what the problem is here.

Comment: Which assembly is 'WTileMap' defined in? does 'Main' Assembly have reference to the assembly where 'WTileMap' is defined in?

Comment: WTileMap is also in the Engine assembly, and the Main Assembly has access to the Engine Assembly.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct `ResourceManager` and that you don't have some other class with the same name? Also, have you tried rebuilding both projects?

Comment: How are you referencing the Engine assembly?  Sounds like it's not seeing the most recent version.  IF your projects are intertwined this way it will be easier to put them in one solution so the dependency is built automatically.

Comment: What does gameInfo.StartingMap return?